# How to omit data type tags in SnakeYaml?

Tags: parsing, yaml, snakeyaml

I have the following 1.1 YAML generated by SnakeYaml

```
'test_jbgrp1':
  'tags': []
  'jobs':
  - 'test_job1'
  'reserve': []
  'cancel':
  - 'max_duration': !!int '1200'
```

The `!!int` tag is breaking another (older) piece of software and I have a requirement to remove the tag before writing the file. I don't want to revert to a silly solutions such as writing content to a String and postprocessing it before dumping the file so the question is - is there a setting in Snakeyaml that would remove `!!int` from the code above?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have to remove all occurences of the `!!int`

You can take a look at the [How to skip a property](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/howto#How_to_skip_a_JavaBean_property) to skip the property or do some transformation using [Flexible Scalar Type Customization](https://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/howto#How_to_configure_scalar_style_or_flow_style_for_JavaBean_propert)

In short you configure `Yaml` instance as below

```
Yaml yaml = new Yaml(new MyRepresenter());
String output = yaml.dump(new MyJavaBean());
```

where MyRepresenter is expressed as below

```
@Override
protected NodeTuple representJavaBeanProperty(Object javaBean, Property property,
                        Object propertyValue, Tag customTag) {
       if (int.class.equals(property.getType())) {//some better condition
          //construct NodeTupe as you wish - i.e. keep the element and remove the type
          return null;//this will skip the property
       } else {
          return super
                     .representJavaBeanProperty(javaBean, property, propertyValue, customTag);
       }
}
```